# How to intergrate medium-editor-insert-plugin with laravel 5.5

Tags: image-uploading, laravel-5.5, medium-editor, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I have been trying to upload images to my Medium-editor using the Medium-editor-insert-plugin with Laravel5.5 for days without success.

To me it seems like the image is to passing to the sever and I don't know why.
I am using the latest release version of medium-editor-insert-plugin.

here is my javascript code to initiate the medium-insert-plugin:

```
$(function () {
    $('.body-editable').mediumInsert({
        editor: bodyEditor,
         addons: {
            images: { 
                fileUploadOptions: {
                    url: 'upload',
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and the route to send the request to the back-end look like this.

```
// upload image route for MediumInsert plugin
Route::post('upload', 'PostsController@upload');
```

and inside my controller i am return all the request data like this:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        return array('data:'=> $request->all());
        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
            //'upload_dir' => public_path().'uploads/',
            'upload_dir' => 'uploads/',
            'upload_url' => 'posts/upload/',
        ));

    }
```

but after use the plugin to insert an image to the editor i am get this error

[image: error from the console]

But in my network response i am getting this.

```
{"data:":{"files":[{}]}}
```

Please can someone tell me what to do?  have been trying to edited the plugin itself but no way till now.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably return only the data object property.

```
{"files":[{}]}
```